# Como encontrar link/referência dentro deste código para uma outra página?

Tags: link

Estou tentando fazer um popup como este encontrado neste link: "http://shoowplay.tk/embed/v2626", ao inspecionar a pagina conseguir fazer praticamente tudo, porém este código http://yourjavascript.com/180361102107/popup.js não consigo, **eu precisaria encontrar dentro deste código um link que faz referência a outra págin**a, porém me parece que está criptografado (como se o link estivesse em pedaços). Alguém poderia me ajudar neste sentido?

Comment: tó ta ai a decriptografia do q vc quer  https://jsfiddle.net/jroLvoz8/

Comment: Perfeito parceiro, é isso mesmo, agora sem querer abusar rs, depois de alterar o que desejo, pra criptografar novamente como faço? Nesse mesmo site ai temo como?

Comment: so fazer o inverço perceba q a função abaixo da parte criptografada he o q descriptografa . entao faça uma função inversa ou simpelsmente cole o texto descriptografado direto